# Angular: How to style dynamically generated html?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a generated element `sub` from this line of code with a `[sub]` property

```html
      <li [displayMode]="displayMode" template-menu-item style="cursor: pointer" [routerLink]="['/request/checkoutReview']" icon="fa-shopping-cart" name="Checkout" id="checkout-menu-icon" [sub]="(products$ | async)?.length"></li>
```

[image]

I'm trying to style the `sub` element that is generated because the alignment is set to `bottom: -.25em;`

I'm trying to set my own styles for it but none of the styles are being applied.

```css
    #checkout-menu-icon > a > div > sub {
        top: 0 !important;
        left: 3px !important;
    }
```

and

```css
    #checkout-menu-icon > a > div > .ng-star-inserted {
        top: 0 !important;
        left: 3px !important;
    }
```

How can I apply styles to the `sub` element below?

```html
     <li id="checkout-menu-icon" name="Checkout" style="cursor: pointer" template-menu-item="" _nghost-c13="" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/request/checkoutReview" ng-reflect-icon="fa-shopping-cart" ng-reflect-name="Checkout" ng-reflect-sub="1" ng-reflect-display-mode="0" class="ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-c13="" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="/request/checkoutReview" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active" href="/request/checkoutReview">
                           <!--bindings={
                              "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
                            }-->
           <span _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-star-inserted" style="color: rgb(69, 69, 69);">
           <i _ngcontent-c13="" class="fa fa-2x fa-shopping-cart" ng-reflect-klass="fa fa-2x" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa-shopping-cart"></i></span>

           <div _ngcontent-c13="" class="tabName" style="color: rgb(69, 69, 69);">Checkout
                            <!--bindings={
                            "ng-reflect-ng-if": "1"
                            }-->
               <sub _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-star-inserted">1</sub>
           </div>
         </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Try adding your styles to the main **styles.css** file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue you're having has to do with how Angular handles [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation). If you add your styles to your main **styles.css** file that should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there another way than using the global styles.css?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of for dynamically generated elements. So long as you use unique/specific class names for your styles it won't be an issue having them defined in your main styles.css file though.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the styles you added and just add the styles below:-

```
#checkout-menu-icon sub {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: can you post something in stackblitz so I can check?